# what would be the benefit of adding a dns server to isc-dhcp-server

Tags: networking, router, dns, dhcp

I have a very simple networking setup. I have a couple server applications like plexmediaserver, transmission-daemon, samba, etc... My router just went down, so instead of buying a new router, I just configured my server to be a router. Which works beautifully. I even installed isc-dhcp-server to it, with the following config.

```
log-facility local7;
ddns-update-style none;
option domain-name-servers 71.10.216.1, 71.10.216.2;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
option routers 10.0.0.1;

subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 10.0.0.50 10.0.0.100;
}
```

Would installing a dns server be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot depends on what you want to do, but probably not.

There are 2 reasons to do so. One is that your ISP's DNS servers are poor and in that case you are better off using OpenDNS or Google's DNS servers.

The second is that you want to be able to access internal resources from both your LAN and from the Internet with the same address. Running your own DNS would let you do that. E.g. you want to access the Plex server from a laptop both inside the house and when you are out without changing the name.

There is a 3rd of course: you want to learn about DNS servers!

Comment: The third option sounds pretty great! :D That really helped.

Comment: I can't really agree on #1, since adding in another layer or DNS servers is just going to make your ISP's responses slower, changing the upstream DNS provider is the right solution.  #2 is really the biggest reason in my book.

Comment: @heavyd Thanks for the input, that definitely makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Well there are some edge cases for #1 but in general I agree with you which is what I said.